# Bad int value BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following column of strings like:

```
1635188264984-384-2141356
```

And I'd like it as an integer type

```
16351882649843842141356
```

But when I use the following query:

```
cast(REPLACE(my_table.my_column,'-','') as int)
```

I get the following error in BigQuery:

```
Bad int64 value: 16351882649843842141356
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I accomplish converting string such as this to integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range for INT is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (see more at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#integer_type)

So, use NUMERIC instead as in below example

```
cast(REPLACE(my_table.my_column,'-','') as numeric)
```